# IIS running error in Azure (Unmarshaling)

Tags: azure, iis

I deploy an ASP.NET Web Forms project in Azure. Suddenly I got error in IIS as it's not working and below event error found from Event View: -

```
An unmarshaling policy check was performed when unmarshaling a custom marshaled object and the class {45FB4600-E6E8-4928-B25E-50476FF79425} was rejected
```

Search solution in Azure but not found. Have anyone any idea that how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The event log error is irrelevant (according to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/15703083-fix-bug-in-agent). So about why your WebForms app fails, you need to debug further yourself, or involve its developers.

Comment: May I know if your project works fine on azure firstly and then suddenly not working or it's not working once you deploy it to azure ? And it seems the error message may not related to your issue, could you please provide more details ?

Comment: It's work properly at first but suddenly this error comes from last couple of days. Also, IIS not working until restart.

Comment: I think the information provided is not enough to help you solve this issue. For this issue, you can [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) a support ticket on azure to ask azure support team for help. They can help you check the backend logs.